# Multi-user restful api using spring boot, jpa and security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a multi user api, where users log in to a restful service and have their own space for say a booking class.  Bookings are not shared between users.

I'm struggling to understand what the best pattern is to create this, while utilizing as much as possible of the magic of spring boot.

I'm using Spring Boot JPA and defining a User and Booking class with @Entity.

My booking then references this user class.  However is there a way I can use @RepositoryRestResource or a similar annotation to automatically isolate data models for each user then use Spring Security to secure the CRUD endpoint or do I need to create my own @RestResponse that looks up users based on their Authorization and then create a findByUser method to perform the isolation?

(note i'm new to Spring, Spring Boot etc)

Edit: it's been suggested I look into ACLs, but i'm struggling to find good SIMPLE resources explaining how they work

Comment: I've also found a video tutorial that uses annotations to limit to specific users (towards the end of the video) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1EFB6fk2_8&list=PLTgRMOcmRb3Oenxtwc-F3kQL8B_7mWdgx&index=3&spfreload=1

Answer (score 7):

If you really have isolated data for each user and you want a transparent mechanism to be able to select or update only the data you are allowed to see you should look T eclipselink's multitenancy support.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/Indigo/Multi-Tenancy

Here is a question with accepted answer about setting this up in spring-data-jpa
[Multi tenancy with spring data jpa and eclipselink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588525/multi-tenancy-with-spring-data-jpa-and-eclipselink)

Also hibernate seems to have support for multitenancy 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#d5e3197

But keep in mind that queries on multitenancy enabled entities are then  always filtered by the tenant id - so the separation is quite strict.

Comment: Awesome - Thanks for that.  Looks super interesting.  Seems to be more for situations where you require full separation.

Comment: Exactly - I would only use it if you really need the full separation of data - but you can switch it on on entity level - so you do not have to enable tenancy on all your entities